# How to redefine a set between runs in AMPL

Tags: optimization, modeling, linear-programming, ampl

I have a model in AMPL. This model must run three times and in each iteration the result must redefine the size of a previously defined set.

Example:

```
set item := 1..12;
...
var out{other_set} >=0 integer;
```

The model would run and get me the solution in out. Then I want to redefine the `item` set as:

```
set item := 1..out.
```

Is this possible?

In page 462 of the manual I found this:

```
Recursive definitions of indexed sets are allowed, so long as the assigned
values can be computed in a sequence that only references previously computed values.
```

Am I right in thinking this is what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a new value to a set. To do so first make sure that it doesn't have a `:=` in the declaration. You can replace it with the default clause:

```
set item default 1..12;
```

Then use the `let` statement to assign the new value:

```
let item := 1..out;
```

Note that in your example `out` is indexed over a set so you'll need to provide a subscript `out[...]`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this in the following days and I will let you know the outcome.